# Magento 2 page-header background color

Tags: magento2, css, header

I want to change the background color to black on luma theme page-header. i am using luma as my default template - what is the best way to go about? - 
I am using github version fresh Magento 2 install, the templates are store in `frontend/Magento/Luma` - firebug directs me to `{.page-header}` `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to add simple styling to a magento 2 store is to add your code here:

ADMIN > CONTENT > Design > CONFIGURATION

Click Edit for the appropriate view (global, website or store) and Theme (in your case Luma):

Open tab HTML Head, under Scripts and Style Sheets, you can add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (min-width: 768px), print {
 .page-header {
   background-color: black
}
</style>
```

Click Save Configuration

Clear Cache

Comment: And if you only want to change the grey bar at the top <style type="text/css">@media (min-width: 768px), print {.page-header .panel.wrapper {background-color: #39c} </style>

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity you can try to change the color in app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less:

```
@header__background-color: @color-black;
@header-panel__background-color: @color-black;
```

then clear **pub/static** and **var/view_preprocessed** directories and subdirectories, except for pub/static/.htaccess.

though this direct change is obviously discouraged. You need to create [a custom theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).

Comment: _module.less? this file is not part of web/css/source

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less. this less file will be used to create css. Have you already tried to change it?

Comment: found the _module.less - it did not work.. deleted var/view_preprocessed, cache and pub/static/ also  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I was able to achieve by adding  background-color: #000; under .page-header { ....the above method didnt work. is it possible to call in image as my background from there ?

Comment: i tried this to _module.less, background-image: url("@{base-url}/images/bg.png"); it didnt work - any suggestions

Comment: As I can see in the code it should be like this "url('@{baseDir}images/bg.png')". Was you able to check with @header__background-color: @color-black; ? Are you sure that var/view_preprocessed, cache and pub/static/ are empty and you invoke php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy on empty folders?

Comment: i did, which makes no sense it should have worked because the line already exists for  @header-panel__background. cleared all the cache  pub/static and var/view_preprocessed. no luck, but it did work background-color: #000; under .page-header . what is my baseDir, where should the image be uploaded?

Comment: So you, overrided "background-color, @header__background-color" with "background-color: #000" and now you try to check "@header__background-color: @color-black" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35881/discussion-between-roger-and-arkadii-chyzhov).

Answer (score 0):

.page-header {
  background-image: url("/logoimages/Violets_Bgnd2.png");
}