# Changing Luma Panel Header CSS

Tags: magento2, header.panel

I am attempting to change the background color of the panel header in Luma. I want the entire header area (everything above the navigation bar) to be black. I found this similar question, which helped, but did not fix the entire issue. I included it below for reference.

I still have a huge white area that I want to be black and I can't figure out which element I need to add a style tag for. I inspected the elements and found and changed the page-wrapper, panel wrapper, and panel header to set them black. None of those items seem to be the white area. I can't figure out what the element is called or how to fix it. I'm editing this in the ADMIN > CONTENT > Design > CONFIGURATION area.

[Magento 2 page-header background color](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102060/magento-2-page-header-background-color)

A picture of what I'm trying to change (the white and gray parts):
[image]
Any advice would be super helpful. I'm a beginner and I'm just trying to get the hang of it. I'm mainly wondering if I am completely missing the element name or if there's something else I need to change.

Here is a link to the store:
http://ec2-52-14-7-55.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

This is what I currently have in the configuration area:

```
<style type="text/css">@media (min-width: 768px), print {

.page-header {
   background-color: black
}
.panel-header {
   background-color: black
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the color of that header use the following code:

```
.panel.header{
 background-color: #000;
 }
```